# Why can't I deploy translation for a metadata owned by a managed package?

Tags: metadata-api, translation, translation-workbench

I retrieved a translation metadata via the Metadata API with the following `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <version>57.0</version>
</Package>
```

What I got was the following `da.translation` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customApplications>
        <label><!-- Accounting --></label>
        <name>Accounting</name>
    </customApplications>

    <!-- some more lines of XML here -->

    <quickActions>
        <label><!-- New Case --></label>
        <name>New_Case_Quick_Action</name>
    </quickActions>

    <!-- some more lines of XML here -->

</Translations>
```

What I did next was setting up the label for the `New_Case_Quick_Action` Quick Action and then deploying it back to the same Environment. Couldn't do so, though, as I received an error:

> In field: name - no QuickAction named New_Case_Quick_Action found

After an investigation, it turned out that it is a managed package-owned Action on the Account object. It creates a new Case. I can translate it in the Translation Workbench at the "Override" section.

I don't mind translating some components manually, but does anybody know why were they retrieved to the `da.translation` file in the first place if they are impossible to deploy? Is there any workaround to this problem?

**Possible hint (?):** It's a Sandbox created out of the already functioning Production environment with a couple of packages installed. Maybe I should reinstall some?

Comment: Have you tried changing the name in the file to `namespace__New_Case_Quick_Action`, where you substitute the package's namespace in place of `namespace`?

Comment: @PhilW wow, it worked, thanks for that. But here comes the hard part - I have 30k-lines XML in front of me and it looks like I would need to update a pretty big chunk of code. Isn't there really any other way to handle these translations?

Comment: Exactly how did you get the XML exported in the first place? It should include the namespace automagically... it rather seems like a bug in the API...

Comment: @PhilW In a couple of ways: 1. In VSC - right click on the `package.xml` that I provided in the question -> `SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org` || 2. A direct command in PowerShell `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r .\manifest -k .\manifest\translations.xml --unzip`, where `translations.xml` is the same as mentioned before. || 3. A direct command in PowerShell `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Translations:da` || Always the same result, a 30k-liner with content without specified namespaces.

Comment: I suggest you raise a support case. This sounds like a bug.

Comment: You may find you can restrict the retrieval to specific namespace/package. If you can then fixing the file is easy with global search/replace.